# Building a "stelaser" - a star-powered maser network that distributes free global electricity. Why and Why not?

Tags: laser, power, space, x-rays, microwaves

I wish to design a Space Based Power platform that delivers microwave power from space. This approach has been criticized (famously by Elon Musk), because converting sunlight to electrons to microwaves and back to electrons introduces too much inefficiency. However, I have a somewhat novel approach for generating microwaves and I'm hoping y'all will be able to explain why or why not this would work.

Firstly, we park at least 3 satellites in orbit around the sun. These satellites have huge mirrors that align, to create a ring-configuration laser, where the lasing-medium is the excited hydrogen in the atmosphere of the sun. Hydrogen lases in the 140nm range, producing a x-ray laser which we can direct outward to space.

Secondly, we "step-down" those x-rays to a microwaves, by pumping a solid-state maser with the x-ray laserbeam. This microwave laser will be of a frequency specific to penetrate Earth's atmosphere (2-5ghz).

Lastly, we transmit that microwave laser through another network of mirrored GEO satellites, which send that free power to Earth.

Comment: Explain how the 'excited hydrogen' is in a population inversion as required for a laser?

Comment: The delta-v requirements to circularize in low solar orbit are _very_ high.

Comment: [These](https://youtu.be/0Ap4JhPoPQY?t=1270) [links](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143905) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Lasers (even very-high-frequency) don't magically protect you from beam collimation issues.  Your energy still spreads out with distance.  Sending energy at a distance greater than the moon is going to require enormous transmitters and receivers or you're only going to get a teeny fraction of the power.   If you want to bounce it off an intermediate satellite, that will again reduce your efficiency.

Communication over these distances work because we can use an amplifier to pump up the small received signal.  That's not productive for energy transmission.

We can generate gigawatts of power just from regular panels in earth orbit.  It's unclear there's benefit to a design with potentially more power from near the sun.  The problem is already getting it down to the ground cheaply enough.

You'd have to not only build the infrastructure to do this, you have to convince the investors that you can make a profit.  Can you build that infrastructure and sell power to customers for less than they would pay for other sources?

If you have to have a receiver on earth that's several miles wide to receive the power, how many can you build?  Even unlimited power at one location can't be shipped great distances without high costs.

From a physics point of view, it is possible to beam energy from one location to another.  But you need very large receivers.  It's hard to make an economic case for building the space infrastructure to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The recovering ex-engineer weighs in.

Imagine the beam of megawatt microwave energy aimed at the receiving station on earth misses its target by a teensy weensy bit and hits Topeka or Oshkosh by mistake. Buildings burn down and/or people walking down the street explode into clouds of bloody steam.

I would definitely *not* want to be the manager responsible for the people writing tens of thousands of lines of control system code for aiming all those mirrors. One glitch and poof!